# Slot Machine - Output not correct

Tags: java, eclipse

the code works fine. However there is one slight problem, if the latter two numbers are the same the code says no numbers match. For Example:

0 2 2 
No numbers match
Play again? (Y/N?)

where obviously it should say:

0 2 2 
Two numbers match
Play again? (Y/N?)

how can I change the code so it does this?

Thanks

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SlotMachine {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int slotOne;
    int slotTwo;
    int slotThree;
    String userResponse;

    do{

        Random randomNumbers = new Random();

        slotOne = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  
        slotTwo= randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  
        slotThree = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  


        System.out.println(slotOne + " " + slotTwo +  " " + slotThree + " " );  
        if (slotOne != slotTwo && slotOne != slotThree) 
        { 
            System.out.println("No numbers match");  
        }
        else if (slotOne == slotTwo && slotOne == slotThree) 
        { 
            System.out.println("All three match - jackpot"); 
        } 
        else
        { 
            System.out.println("Two numbers match"); 
        }       

        System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N?)");
        userResponse = scan.next();
    }

    while (userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    do{
        if(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))

        {
            System.out.print("Thank You.");
            userResponse = scan.next();
        }
        else if (!userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N?)");
            userResponse = scan.next();
        }
    }
    while (!userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    scan.close();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you count the matches, `a == b`, `b == c` and `a == c` like

```
System.out.println(slotOne + " " + slotTwo +  " " + slotThree + " " );  
int count = 0;
if (slotOne == slotTwo) count++;
if (slotOne == slotThree) count++;
if (slotTwo == slotThree) count++;
if (count == 3) {
    System.out.println("All three match - jackpot");
} else if (count > 0) {
    System.out.println("Two numbers match");
} else {
    System.out.println("No numbers match");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part is wrong:

```
        if (slotOne != slotTwo && slotOne != slotThree)
```

Because if slot two and slot three are the same, it could still return true.

Change it to this:

```
        if (slotOne != slotTwo && slotOne != slotThree && slotTwo != slotThree)
```

Then it checks for all three numbers
This way, you only need to change one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logic error here:

```
  if (slotOne != slotTwo && slotOne != slotThree) 
        { 
            System.out.println("No numbers match");  
        }
```

does not work for inputs 0 2 2 because the first if statement evaluates to true and so
it mistakenly believes that because 1 does not match 2 and 1 does not match 3, the
code thinks, then 2 must not match 3! which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it in the first if statement: `(slotOne != slotTwo && slotOne != slotThree && slotTwo != slotThree)`

the correct code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SlotMachine {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int slotOne;
    int slotTwo;
    int slotThree;
    String userResponse;

    do{

        Random randomNumbers = new Random();

        slotOne = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  
        slotTwo= randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  
        slotThree = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);  


        System.out.println(slotOne + " " + slotTwo +  " " + slotThree + " " );  
        if (slotOne != slotTwo && slotOne != slotThree && slotTwo != slotThree) 
        { 
            System.out.println("No numbers match");  
        }
        else if (slotOne == slotTwo && slotOne == slotThree) 
        { 
            System.out.println("All three match - jackpot"); 
        } 
        else
        { 
            System.out.println("Two numbers match"); 
        }       

        System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N?)");
        userResponse = scan.next();
    }

    while (userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    do{
        if(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))

        {
            System.out.print("Thank You.");
            userResponse = scan.next();
        }
        else if (!userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N?)");
            userResponse = scan.next();
        }
    }
    while (!userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    scan.close();

}
}
```